# Is there any digital wartermark technology for raw text?

Tags: watermark

I have a demand to protect my data which can accessed by my client privately.
My data is not in any document but in [plain text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text), e.g., a JSON string.
I want to protect my data against being modified, then redistributing without my permission.

I researched online for a while, and concluded that,

- there are digital watermark methods for protecting images, audio, videos or documents (pdf, MS Word doc or other format),
- but there is no methods for raw text.

Is my conclusion correct? If so, why is it not possible to develop a watermark for raw text? If not, can you give me a hint to implement a watermark for raw text?

Sorry for my poor English. I will appreciate for you answer and editing.

Comment: What is the way you are distributing the raw text to your client? either API response or something else?

Comment: Yes, token authenticated API might be one method to access my data, but bulk access is also allowed.

Comment: Is you are using token based authentication, what is the need for watermark. Token based itself is a security right?

Comment: If I have two client, Alice and Bob. Both of them can access a same piece of data D by there private token unknown by any third party. But I find Carol have some some data D' looks like modified from D. I want to have a solution to verify  that is D'  modified from D and who is the person leakage my data.

Comment: @Pig8 the 'Avoid secret-dependent loops' in cryptography is an EXAMPLE, not an INTRODUCTION (read the title of the section) .. also i note you haven't made any proposed changes. Consider making some and they will be reviewed!

Answer (score 3):

Normally sound and picture contains some watermark in frequency domain that is invisible to eye or can't be heard by a man.

Watermarks in word or pdf documents are rather easy to remove, because these are often visible and easy to find. In case of pictures, movies or sound some watermarks could be very hard to find - so it is harder to remove such watermark.

In case of raw text you can insert some pattern of white spaces or special characters that are invisible, but this could be easily removed.

Comment: Do you know some technique to insert white or non-printable patterns which can be verified later?

Comment: Just generate some String constructed from such characters, then append it somwhere to the text, then when you read the file search it for this "watermark" pattern. If you use this text as input to your program, remeber to make tests to ensure compatibility - that your code is able to process such "watermarked" message as some frameworks could have problems with that.

Comment: You method could be not called a digital watermark, since a watermark should have invisable, robust properties. It would be easy  to tamper-proofed by advanced bad person.

Comment: Any watermark could be removed by "advanced bad person" :) It depends only how much time and effort someone is willing to spend. Watermark technology doesn't make any guarantees that  "advanced bad person" couldn't remove or tamper the watermark. In case of raw text there are not so many options to hide some invisible "watermark" information. Text files are easy to process and that's why they are easy to remove any kind of "watremark" or unwanted information from them.

Answer (score 3):

While lossy data like images, audio & videos can have watermark using steganography due to their tolerance to noise, text data, especially JSON which have specific format can't survive simple "Format Document" which will throw away any special character tricks you put.

What you can do is essentially license/build your own DRM scheme. So your client must be using a special program, that accept encrypted file from your server, which it will decrypt with client-specific key (using asymmetric encryption). This address identification of leak (since you can trivially check the key owner, remember, only you can encrypt the data, while the clients can only decrypt data meant for them) and modification (because the encryption will fail on modification).

Of course, if your client can simply display the decrypted file in your program and manually copy it into a new JSON, that's an [analog hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_hole) you need to somehow close (perhaps makes the JSON data so convoluted it can only be used by yet another app under your control?)

Depending on what the JSON data is used for, it might be simpler to just switch to a proprietary file format, force your client to use the file format with approved apps that won't leak the raw JSON data (that's how DRM enforcement works anyway).